# What are the default stdin and stdout for a program started from desktop on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, stdout, stdin, desktop

When I start a program from desktop (Ubuntu 16.04) instead of from shell so that the program is not associated with a terminal, what are the stdin and stdout for this program? Are `STDIN_FILENO` and `STDOUT_FILENO` valid file descriptors when the program starts? Where does `printf` write to in this case?

Comment: Why not try it? In Windows, it opens a console window if `stdout` is used, which closes on exit. Unless there is a prompt or a pause at the end of the program, it can happen so quickly that you don't even see the window before the screen is refreshed.

Comment: @WeatherVane I tried compiling a Hello World program in C using gcc on Ubuntu. Then I double-clicked the executable on desktop, and nothing happened (no terminal pops up). I still can't find out how are stdin and stdout set for this program when I started it this way.

Comment: Did you put in a pause at the end of the program as I suggested?

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes I did put a `pause()` function which is declared in `unistd.h`.

Comment: Was there a `newline` or `fflush(stdout)` at the end of your "Hello, world!" message to ensure it was actually sent to output before the program ended?

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, there is a `\n` at the end.

Comment: The standard only requires flushing `stdout` on newline if the device is interactive (e.g. C99, Section 7.19.3, para 7).    However, what constitutes an interactive device is implementation defined (e.g. C99, Section 5.1.2.3, para 6).    It would not be particularly surprising if `stdout` was not deemed an interactive device if the program was started on a linux desktop (after all, other means are used to interact with the user).    So you probably need to use `fflush(stdout)` as well.

Comment: It depends on your desktop environment, but I would guess the standard descriptors are being redirected to `/dev/null`. You can `ls -l /proc/$pidOfYourProgram/fd` to check it.

Comment: @WeatherVane be rest assured that nothing remotely similar happens in any standard Linux DE.

Comment: @n.m. I used your command to check and found that file descriptor 0 is redirected to `/dev/null`, but 1 and 2 are redirected to `socket:[24624]`. What does `socket:[24624]` mean? Is it a file?

Comment: It is probably a unix domain socket. There is probably some daemon that reads from this socket and dumps the content to some kind of log file.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks. This is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `strace` program to see all system calls a program is executing (like open, read, write, close). When you attatch it to the "Desktop program" (the one running your program; use `pstree` or `proctree`), you can see what happens to file descriptors 0, 1 and 2.

See https://superuser.com/questions/606985/any-way-to-view-stdout-of-a-program-after-it-has-been-started-in-gnome-shell

Or google for "gnome run program stdout"